# Creating a bundled product with Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've been following along with this example: [Magento programmaticaly create bundle Product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584034/magento-programmaticaly-create-bundle-product)

and the code is working when I create a new product, however, I can't get it to work when I load a product either bundled or simple. [EDIT] I can load a bundled product that I created programmatically through the code below and add products to the bundle. A bundled product I created through the GUI I cannot add products too.

Any idea how I can load a product up then bundle it with another a product?

Here is my current code:

```
    $items = array();
$items[] = array(
    'title'     => 'Bundle Option',
    'option_id' => '',
    'delete'    => '',
    'type'      => 'radio',
    'required'  => 1,
    'position'  => 0,
);

$selectionRawData = array();
$selectionRawData[0] = array();
$selectionRawData[0][] = array(
    'selection_id'             => '',
    'option_id'                => '',
    'product_id'               => 3,
    'delete'                   => '',
    'selection_price_value'    => 0,
    'selection_price_type'     => 0,
    'selection_qty'            => 1,
    'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,
    'position'                 => 0,
    'is_default'               => 1,
);

$selections = $selectionRawData;

$websiteIDs = array(1);
$cats = array(4);

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

// load product
// NOT WORKING
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->load(127);


// new product
/******
 * THIS WORKS

$p = array(
            'sku_type' => 1,
            'sku' => '123321',
            'name' => "BarProduct",
            'description' => 'Foo',
            'short_description' => 'Bar',
            'type_id' => 'bundle',
            'attribute_set_id' => 4,
            'weight_type' => 0,
            'visibility' => 4,
            'price_type' => 1,
            'price_view' => 0,
            'price' => 1.99,
            'has_options' => 1,
            'required_options' => 1,
            'status' => 1,
            'created_at' => strtotime('now'),
            'category_ids' => $cats,
            'store_id' => 0,
            'website_ids' => $websiteIDs,
            'weight' => 0,
            'weight_type' => 1,
            'delivery_time' => '',
            'generate_meta' => 1,
            'tax_class_id' => 1, //19%
    );
    $product->setData($p);

*****/ 

Mage::register('product', $product);
Mage::register('current_product', $product);

$product->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(false);
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

$product->setBundleOptionsData($items);
$product->setBundleSelectionsData($selections);
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
$product->setCanSaveBundleSelections(true);
$product->setAffectBundleProductSelections(true);

$product->save();

$result['product_name'] = $product->getId();
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some funky stuff going on with my product index. I deleted all my products and fixed my index and this now works, albeit not well.

So here is what I gleaned from the process:

If you want to take two simple products and bundle them, you'll need to create a new bundled bundled product via the `$p = array` code above, then add both simple products.

Otherwise, you'll need a bundled product that is premade via the magento gui. then you'll have bring up that product using the $product->load(product_id) command, then add your simple products to that.

Answer (score 1):

This is important for bundled products:

```
$product->setData("price_type", 0);
```

You must set this attribute to 0 (Dynamic price) before saving.
Reindexing is then necessary of course.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete all unneeded options like this:

```
$optionsselectionsmap = array();
        $options = Mage::getModel("bundle/option")->getCollection()->setProductIdFilter($product->getId());
        foreach($options as $option){
            $selection = Mage::getModel("bundle/selection")->getCollection()->setOptionIdsFilter($option->getId())->getFirstItem();
            $tmp = array();
            $tmp['option_id'] = $option->getId();
            $tmp['selection_id'] = $selection->getData('selection_id');
            $optionsselectionsmap[$selection->getData('sku')] = $tmp;
        }

$deleteoptionids = array();
        foreach($optionsselectionsmap as $k=>$v) $deleteoptionids[] = $v['option_id'];
        foreach($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsCollection($product) as $deleteitem){
            $deleteitem = $deleteitem->getData();
            $deleteitem['delete'] = 1;
            $bundleOptions[] = $deleteitem;
        }
```